# Cartesian product in Mata

Tags: set, stata, cartesian-product

To construct a set of vectors, I'll need to take the Cartesian product of sets C[1]..C[d],

D := {x : x[i] ϵ C[i], i = 1..d}

*Example*: If `*C[1]=(5,6,7)';*C[2]=(3,5,6)';*C[3]=(1,3,5)'`, then some elements of `D` are (5,3,1), (5,3,3) ...

**I would like to know**: What is the best way to take the Cartesian product in Mata, generally? I have found a clumsy approach for d=3, illustrated below.

---

*Detailed example*. This code should illustrate what I have tried and the desired output. The `mm_expand` function comes from `ssc install moremata`.

```
mata

// prep

lo = (5,3,1)'
hi = (7,6,5)'
all = uniqrows((lo\hi))

n_cols = length(lo)
n_vals = length(all)

c_list = J( 1,n_cols,NULL )
c_lens = J( 1,n_cols,0 )

for (i=1;i<=n_cols;i++){
    c_list[i] = &(select( all,all :>= lo[i] :& all :<= hi[i] ))
    c_lens[i] = length(*c_list[i])
}   

// question: How should I take this Cartesian product?

grid_box = 
mm_expand(*c_list[1],c_lens[2]*c_lens[3],0,1),
mm_expand(mm_expand(*c_list[2],c_lens[1],0,1),c_lens[3],0,0),
mm_expand(*c_list[3],c_lens[1]*c_lens[2],0,0)

// (just fyi) my next step

is_decr = ! rowsum( grid_box[,1..(n_cols-1)]-grid_box[,2..n_cols] :< 0 )
select(grid_box,is_decr)

end
```

The notation and the "prep" part of the code are related to [my application](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1115531/using-inequalities-to-find-vertices-of-a-polytope).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use recursion:

```
real matrix cart_prod(pointer vector c_list ,| real scalar curr_i){
    if(curr_i==.) curr_i=1
    myret = (*c_list[curr_i])
    if (curr_i<length(c_list)){
        ret = cart_prod(c_list, curr_i+1)
        myret = mm_expand(myret,rows(ret),1,1), mm_expand(ret, rows(myret),1,0)
    }
    return(myret)
}
cart_prod(c_list)
```

This will work even if the vectors pointed to from `c_list` are of different lengths.

Comment: Thanks! I'm accepting your elegant solution, but also posting my own, since I suspect it is a little faster.

Answer (score 0):

Each column of the result only needs to be `mm_expand`ed twice. It should be faster to construct the columns directly in that way (rather than in d-k steps for the kth column, as in @BeingQuisitive's answer).

```
function prod(x,| real scalar need_int){
    y = exp(sum(log(x)))
    if (need_int==0) return(y)
    return(round(y))
}

function cartem(pointer vector vlist){

    // input: vlist should point to column vectors

    d = length( vlist )
    lens = J(1,d,.)
    for (i=1;i<=d;i++){
        lens[i] = length ( *vlist[i] )
    }
    tot_len = prod(lens)
    out = J(tot_len,d,.)

    out[,1] = mm_expand(*vlist[1],round(tot_len/lens[1]),0,1)
    out[,d] = mm_expand(*vlist[d],round(tot_len/lens[d]),0,0)

    if (d == 2) return(out)

    for (i=2;i<=d-1;i++){
        out[,i] = mm_expand(
        mm_expand(*vlist[i],prod(lens[1..i-1]),0,0)
        ,prod(lens[i+1..d]),0,1)
    }

    return(out)
}
```

Here is an example based on my use-case. It shows that the code above produces the same (desired) result as @BeingQuisitive's solution:

```
c_list = (&(7\10),&(5\6\7),&(3\5\6),&(1\3\5))

cartem(c_list) == cart_prod(c_list)
// ^ it's true
```

I'm not well-versed in Stata's benchmarking tools, so I haven't confirmed my suspicion about the efficiency gains.